# How do you keep repeating a song in AS3 FlashCS6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, flash-cs6

I would like to know how do you repeat a song again and again in Flash CS6 using AS3?

currently i have this code:

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("YMCA.mp3"))
var soundChannel:SoundChannel = sound.play();
```

How do I repeat this song when it finishes again and again?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to your soundChannel:

```
soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler);

function soundCompleteHander(e:Event):void {
    sound.play();
}
```

Comment: what is the package i should import? cuz there is undefined property of soundCompleteHandler. Hmm..

Comment: import flash.events.Event; will import the Event.SOUND_COMPLETE but if Flash isn't spotting the soundCompleteHandler you (or I) may have mis-typed it... And, indeed, yes I have just spotted the typo. I'll try to correct it..

Comment: I missed an all-important 'l' in the function name, sorry. It should be soundCompleteHandler, not soundCompleteHander

Answer (score 1):

this will make the sound to loop many times with a flawless and gap-less playback

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("YMCA.mp3"))
var soundChannel:SoundChannel = sound.play(0,999999999);
```